# Which component is better to move data from HDFS into Hive with some data transformation?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I need to load some data from HDFS to Hive. But I need to some aggregations between the files that I've in HDFS. I read that Sqoop can do that but only using MySQL. Which another choices I've to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to create an external table in Hive that sources from your files in HDFS. Then you can create a Hive table to store your aggregated data and some Hive SQL to do the insert into that table.

Comment: But I've some 70 files in HDFS. I think I don't need to create 70 tables in Hive to do the aggregation operation. Is there a way that can I import alll this files into the same table?

Thanks!

Comment: Hive will automatically handle the union of the tables. As long as they are the same structure you only need one external table with the location being the HDFS path to your 70 files.